# preprocessor directive #define doesn't work in .Xresources

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xterm, x-windows

I'm trying to use a [solarized color theme](https://github.com/solarized/xresources) for my `.Xresources` file. I'm using Arch Linux with i3 window manager.

However, it seems that `#define` preprocessor directives do nothing, and the `.Xresources` file that the solarized theme uses has many of them, so as a result, that is completely broken.

I found [another question regarding this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302736/solarized-color-name-not-defined), but the answer doesn't work for me. How can I enable `#define` preprocessor directives in .Xresources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arch Linux has the following code in `/etc/gdm/Xsession` :

```
if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -nocpp -merge "$userresources"
fi
```

The argument `-nocpp` indicates that xrdb should not run the input
through the preprocessor.

The fix is to remove the `-nocpp` option from the above command.

The package containing cpp must be installed.

If using xfce, some people rather recommend using instead of the above :

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc ~/.config/xfce4/
```

and deleting `--nocpp` from the line containing `xrdb -merge`
in `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc`.